# Initializing elements of a map conditionally in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for the best way to conditionally avoid adding an element to a map when it is being initialized/defined. In this case, I want to avoid adding an element to a map if the value for the key is nil.

```
(defn create-record [data]
  (let [res {
    :username (data :username)
    :first-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :first])
    :last-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :last])
    :gender (get-in data [:user-info :sex])
   }])
)
```

I don't want to add gender to the map if the results of the get-in are nil (the sex field in the data does not exist). Is there a way to do this when I create the map? I could remove all keys whose value is nil after I create the map but, in some cases, I want some keys to have nil values and others to not be in the map at all if they would have nil values.

Comment: aside: "gender" != "sex"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would use a combination of `merge` and `when-let` for these optional parameters.

The core idea is to merge in either a single element map or nil for each of the optional parameters.  Merging in nil will do nothing, so you won't see the nil in the map.

```
(defn create-record [data]
  (let [res (merge {:username (data :username)
                    :first-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :first])
                    :last-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :last])}
                   (when-let [gender (get-in data [:user-info :sex])]
                     {:gender gender}))]
    res))
```

Depending on how frequently you need to do this, I would recommend writing a short macro or function around the when-let to keep the code more concise.

Comment: Thanks, this is great - but why the superfluous `(let [res ... res)` wrapper?

Comment: @Alex I was keeping the code as similar as possible to his.  I'm assuming that he may have been doing something else with the result after the assignment, so I left it in there.  You are right in that it's not necessary though.

Comment: Ah thanks, makes sense @deterb. I was worried I was missing something.

Answer (score 3):

```
(cond-> {:username   (data :username)
         :first-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :first])
         :last-name  (get-in data [:user-info :name :last])}
    (get-in data [:user-info :sex]) (assoc :gender (get-in data [:user-info :sex])))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn create-record [data]   
   (merge {:username   (data :username)
           :first-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :first])
           :last-name  (get-in data [:user-info :name :last])}
           (when       
             (get-in data [:user-info :sex]) 
             {:gender (get-in data [:user-info :sex])})))
```

Just add `when` for each element you want to check if it is not `nil` and then it will return a map to be merged or nil that will not affect the return map value.

You can merge several maps together so there is no limit of maps to merge and you can return a separate map for each element that is not `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Building a map and `dissoc`ing the keys which you want to impose conditions upon based on a predicate (here -- `nil?`) might be the simplest approach (NB. this function only tests keys explicitly mentioned as arguments; those not mentioned are never removed, whether the values attached to them satisfy the predicate or not):

```
(defn dissoc-when
  "Dissoc those keys from m which are mentioned among ks and whose
   values in m satisfy pred."
  [pred m & ks]
  (apply dissoc m (filter #(pred (m %)) ks)))
```

At the REPL:

```
user> (dissoc-when nil? {:foo nil :bar true :quux nil} :foo :bar)
{:quux nil, :bar true}
```

Though generally speaking, if you expect to work with a lot of maps representing real world entities of some particular type, you might want to go with records -- and then you can just skip all `nil`s at the stage where you extract values from your input map, because records, when viewed as maps, always seem to include the keys corresponding to their fields. E.g.

```
(defrecord Person [username first-name last-name])
```

Then you can factor out the logic for "schema conversions" between maps:

```
(defn translate-map
  "Transforms the data map in accordance with the spec in table.
   Skips nil-valued entries."
  [data table]
  (->> table
       (keep (fn [[to from]]
               (when-let [from-val (get-in data from)]
                 [to from-val])))
       (into {})))
```

Now your `create-record` function becomes a composition of `translate-map` and `map->Person`:

```
(defn create-person [data]
  (map->Person
   (translate-map data {:username [:username]
                        :first-name [:user-info :name :first]
                        :last-name [:user-info :name :last]
                        :gender [:user-info :sex]})))
```

If you do prefer working with regular maps, you could use something like the following instead for equivalent output:

```
(defn create-person [data]
  (merge (zipmap [:username :first-name :last-name] (repeat nil))
         (translate-map data {:username [:username]
                              :first-name [:user-info :name :first]
                              :last-name [:user-info :name :last]
                              :gender [:user-info :sex]})))
```

At the REPL (record version in Clojure 1.3):

```
user> (create-person {:username "jsmith"
                      :user-info {:name {:first "John" :last "Smith"}}})
#user.Person{:username "jsmith", :first-name "John", :last-name "Smith"}
user> (create-person {:username "jsmith"
                      :user-info {:name {:first "John" :last "Smith"}
                                  :sex :male}})
#user.Person{:username "jsmith", :first-name "John", :last-name "Smith", :gender :male}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
(let [not-nils #{:gender}]
  (defn create-record [data]
    (into {} (for [[k v] {:username (data :username)
                          :first-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :first])
                          :last-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :last])
                          :gender (get-in data [:user-info :sex])}
                   :when (not (and (nil? v) (not-nils k)))]
               [k v]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn create-record [data]
  (let [gender (get-in data [:user-info :sex])]
    (->> {:username (data :username)
          :first-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :first])
          :last-name (get-in data [:user-info :name :last])}
         (#(if gender (assoc % :gender gender) %)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt:

```
(defn exclude-nils-for [m kw-set] 
    (apply hash-map (apply concat (remove (fn [[k v]] (and (kw-set k) (nil? v))) m))))
```

Test:

```
user> (exclude-nils-for {:gender "m" :name "Thomas" :age "24"} #{})
{:age "21", :gender "m", :name "Thomas"}
user> (exclude-nils-for {:gender "m" :name "Thomas" :age "24"} #{:name})
{:age "21", :gender "m", :name "Thomas"}
user> (exclude-nils-for {:gender "m" :name nil :age "24"} #{:name})
{:age "21", :gender "m"}
user> (exclude-nils-for {:gender "m" :name nil :age nil} #{:age})
{:gender "m", :name nil}
```

Comment: You might want to replace `flatten` with `apply concat`, otherwise more complex values cause problems (try adding `:foo [1 2]` to the map in the first example). (Or maybe unwrap one level of parens and make that `apply (comp hash-map concat)`.) Also, I'd add a test for the case where a `nil` value is *not* to be excluded (although this does work).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your fields and which ones are optional:

```
(def fields
[[:username   [:username]]
 [:first-name [:user-info :name :first]]
 [:sex        [:user-info :sex]          true]])
```

and then write a function to use that info:

```
(defn create-record [data keys]
  (->>
    (for [[n k ignore-nil?] keys 
            :let [v (get-in data k)] 
            :when (or (not ignore-nil?) v)]
      [n v])
    (into {})))
```

and it will work like this:

```
; If :sex is missing don't create a field
user=> (create-record {:username "dr" :user-info { :name {:first "Dave"} }} fields)
{:username "dr", :first-name "Dave"}

user=> (create-record {:username "dr" :user-info { :name {:first "Dave"} :sex :m }} fields)
{:username "dr", :first-name "Dave", :sex :m}

; If :first is missing, create a nil field
user=> (create-record {:username "dr" :user-info { :name {} :sex :m }} fields)
{:username "dr", :first-name nil, :sex :m}
```

Modify as needed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to make up new names (for when-let) or repeat gets and do it in one go, here's one more approach:

```clj
(letfn [(cond-assoc [m k v] (if (nil? v) m (assoc m k v)))]
  (-> {}
      (cond-assoc :a 1)
      (cond-assoc :b nil)))
=> {:a 1}
```