# How do I conj to a clojure vector conditionally

Tags: clojure

Is there a cleaner way to do something like the following in clojure?

```
(defn this [x] (* 2 x))
(defn that [x] (inc x))
(defn the-other [x] (-> x this that))

(defn make-vector [thing]
  (let [base (vector (this (:a thing))
                     (that (:b thing)))]
    (if-let [optional (:c thing)]
      (conj base (the-other optional))
      base)))

(make-vector {:a 1, :b 2}) ;=> [2 3]
(make-vector {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}) ;=> [2 3 7]
```

By "cleaner" I mean something closer to this:

```
(defn non-working-make-vector [thing]
  (vector (this (:a thing))
          (that (:b thing))
          (if (:c thing) (the-other (:c thing)))))

(non-working-make-vector {:a 1, :b 2} ;=> [2 3 nil]  no nil, please!
(non-working-make-vector {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3} ;=> [2 3 7]
```

Note that I might want to call some arbitrary function (e.g. `this`, `that`, `the-other`) on any of the keys in `thing` and place the result in the returned vector. The important thing is that if the key doesn't exist in the map it should not put a `nil` in the vector.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8992997/684888) but the output is a vector rather than a map so I can't use `merge`.

Comment: Don't you simply want (vec (vals thing)) ?

Comment: @DiegoBasch: Yup, that what he wants.

Comment: No, sorry @DiegoBasch, I want to be able to call any arbitrary function on a given key. I've edited the example to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn this [x] (* 2 x))
(defn that [x] (inc x))
(defn the-other [x] (-> x this that))

(def k-f-map {:a this
              :b that
              :c the-other})

(def m1 {:a 1 :b 2})
(def m2 {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})

(defn make-vector [k-f-map m]
  (reduce (fn [res [fk fv]]
            (if (fk m)
              (conj res (fv (fk m)))
              res))
          [] k-f-map))

(make-vector k-f-map m1)
-> [2 3]

(make-vector k-f-map m2)
-> [2 3 7]
```

Comment: This is probably the answer stand is looking for. As a minor tweak, in Clojure 1.4 `reduce-kv` would be better suited to the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
;;; replace [:a :b :c] with a vector of arbitrary functions
;;; of your choice, or perhaps accept a seqable of functions
;;; as an extra argument
(defn make-vector [thing]
  (into [] (keep #(% thing) [:a :b :c])))

;;; from the REPL:
(make-vector {:a 1 :b 2})
; => [1 2]
(make-vector {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
; => [1 2 3]
```

Note that `keep` only throws out `nil`; `false` will be included in the output.

Comment: Use e.g. `(filter identity (map #(% thing) ...))` in place of the `keep` call if `false` should be discarded as well.

Comment: See my edit. Is it possible to use `keep` to call some arbitrary function? I suppose I could have some umbrella function that dispatches on the key name but that's starting to get ugly.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you can put arbitrary functions in the seqable passed to `keep` inside `make-vector`. In particular, you can replace `[:a :b :c]` with `[(comp this :a) (comp that :b) (comp the-other :c)]` to obtain a version of `non-working-make-vector`, as currently included in the question text, which does in fact omit any `nil`s from the output. (Or you can spell out `(comp this :a)` as `#(this (:a %))`, of course.) See also `(doc keep)` (basically it works like `map`, but discards `nil`s from the output).

Comment: Hmmm, this isn't really getting to what I'm looking for. My example is not good. Is it better to completely re-edit the question or remove it and re-ask?

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, you want to do your filtering (for presence of key) prior to calling the function on the value (so you don't want to call `this`, `that` or `the-other` from your example on `nil`). In that case, mobyte's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

or using `cond->`?

your `make-vector` function in `cond->` version:

```clj
(defn make-vector [thing]
  (cond-> [(this (:a thing))
           (that (:b thing))]
    (:c thing) (conj (the-other (:c thing)))))
```

you can have more conditions or change :a and :b to be optional as well.